# Navigate to Additional Page Seconds after First Loads

Tags: flutter, dart

Say my app starts on **PageA**, I'm trying to navigate to **PageB** 2 seconds after it loads.

Here is what I've tried...

**In PageA:**

```
Future _sleepTwo() {
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () => "sleeping...");
}

@override
void initState() {
  this._sleepTwo().then((res) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => PageB(),
        ));
  });
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
E/flutter (22949): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
E/flutter (22949): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

I've looked everywhere but got nowhere.

I even tried wrapping everything in `initState()` with a `Future(() => {code here});`. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have a context if the page hasn't initialized. Insert the following code into your `Widget build(BuildContext context)` method.

```
_sleepTwo().then((res) {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => PageB(),
      ));
});
```

Don't use the `await` keyword if you want the PageA to still draw itself, and then after two seconds switch to PageB

Comment: If you look at my example, I used `then`.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder right, your initial code is right, you just need to _**put it in your widget build method**_, because otherwise when you pass context to your navigator it isn't initialized

Comment: You.. are a legend. Thank you so much, it worked. Been stuck on this for days haha.